# Audio with QML - Unable to play a wav file

Tags: c++, qml, qt5.5

3 days I'm stuck with a tricky issue!
I've built an image for my embedded device based on a Colibri T20 board, using Yocto.
I"ve added Qt5, using X11 (because Tegra20 drivers from nvidia support hw accel only with X11...).
At this point, everything works fine.
I've also generated the respective SDK to build application for the respective platform..
Works fine.

I wrote a simple application to play audio file, very basic...just to play wav files...
It does not work. No sound output.

```
import QtMultimedia 5.5

Item {

...
Audio {
 id: audioPlayer
source: "file:///opt/track.wav"
}
..
onClick() {
  idPlayer.play()
}

}
```

This code works fine on my host linux.
But not on my Colibri.
Qt 5.5.1 was firstly built with ALSA, pulseaudio (gstreamer plugins...).
No outpût.

But in the linux, I can play the wav file using:

```
aplay /opt/track.wav
```

So I assume that my alsa driver are up-to-date.

Then, I 've recompiled Qt 5.5.1 without pulseaudio....
It does not work better :(

To be honnest, I'm not very experienced with alsa and pulseaudio matter. I'm very fustrated bzecause I don't understand what's happening under the abstracted layer of QtMultuimedia.

Any suggestion is welcome...This issue is simply driving me mad ;)

Comment: Are there some warning messages? Can you try to test playing in Qt (w/o QML)?

Comment: Yes. I've added this line in the main.cpp:

QSound::play("track.wav");

It works fine on my host linux....but not on my ColibriT20...Arghh.

Comment: Looks strange. Perhaps some sound driver issue. Can you play this wav file with some system player at all?

Comment: Yes. 
aplay track.wav   works pefectly in the console.

Comment: With pure Qt you can write a small application to show the supported codes. Is WAV supported?